# Accessing a REST API from behind a firewall: whitelist the API's outbound IP addresses?

Tags: ip-address, azure

We have two applications. One application exists behind an on-premise site's firewall. It communicates with our second application, a service app that operates a REST API in the Azure cloud.

My question relates to the on-premise firewall. The service app in the Azure cloud has a single static inbound IP address. It also has a slew of outbound IP addresses. I plan to whitelist the Azure service app's inbound IP address. Do I also need to whitelist the outbound IP addresses?

(Does the REST API's response go through the outbound IP, or does the response travel back through another mechanism.)

Comment: Sorry, applications and protocols above the transport layer are explicitly  off topic here, see the [help/on-topic]. For your firewall question we‘ll need more information on what happens on the transport layer and what connects where.

Comment: This isn't an application problem, it's a firewall configuration (at least in concept) problem. If the question said SSH instead of REST it would be on topic.

Comment: OP, without the firewall's configuration your question can't be answered exactly. It is correct that you need to account for connectivity in both directions, however, the way in which your firewall accomplishes this varies with configuration and capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

A REST API call is just a fancy HTTP message, and HTTP is carried over TCP.

A TCP connection is made from one source IP to one destination IP.  In other words, the response will come back from the inbound IP.